# Is it possible to change row position of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, html-table

Is it possible to change the place of a row to the top of the table (first row)

I'am using `firebase` as the source of the data for the table and I cant figure out how to get a row to be the first row when it's click on or it's data been updated

I already set a timestamp when the data of the row been edited so maybe is there a way to get the rows sorted by the timestamp from `firebase`

Here is the code for the table and how I assign the data to it

```
    <div class="tableDiv" align="left">
      <table id="example" class="display" align="center">
        <thead>
          <tr style="color: #c00; background: #FFCC01;">
            <td onclick="sortTable(0)">Date</td>
            <td onclick="sortTable(1)">RR</td>
            <td onclick="sortTable(2)">Origin</td>
            <td onclick="sortTable(3)">Destination</td>
            <td onclick="sortTable(4)">CNEE</td>
            <td onclick="sortTable(5)">Status</td>
            <td>Details</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table_body"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Requests");


rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {


  var DateValue = snap.child("Date").val();
  var RRValue = snap.child("RR").val();
  var OrgValue = snap.child("Origin").val();
  var DestValue = snap.child("Destination").val();
  var CustNameValue = snap.child("Customer Name").val();
  var StatusValue = snap.child("Status").val();

  //table data fetched from firebase
  if (StatusValue == "Pending") {
    $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + DateValue +
      "</td><td class=\"valueRRField\">" + RRValue +
      "</td><td>" + OrgValue +
      "</td><td>" + DestValue + "</td><td>" + CustNameValue
      + "</td><td>" + StatusValue + "</td><td><Button class=\"lisnClick\">" + "Expand" + "</Button></td></tr>");
  }
});
```

Please I need at least hints on how it can be implemented

Comment: Numerous table sorting scripts around. Not entirely clear what you are asking here

Comment: yea i already implemented sorting alphabetically but what im looking for is to take one row and make it to be the first row of the table

Comment: Just append the element before the first child. `var trs = $('#table_body tr'); trs.eq(0).before(trs.eq(3));`. That is, of course, if you're just altering the Client.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data from firebase sorted by the timestamp using Firebase SDK `.orderByChild` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#orderbychild). Make sure the date is in a unit (e.g. milliseconds) since the Unix epoch so that the sorting is handled numerically (and not by a date like "Sunday May 12 2019", for example). You can even have Firebase generate the timestamp for you (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#.TIMESTAMP)

It will look something like:

```js
firebase
  .database()
  .ref('/Requests')
  .orderByChild('timestamp')
```

You can certainly manipulate the DOM and move a row from one spot to the top, but I think re-rendering with the updated data will produce better code, and you have the benefit of Firebase updating in real time. To move a row, you would just need to get a reference to the parent element, the item it will precede once moved, and it (e.g. using `querySelector`) and then you can use `insertBefore` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore. Prepend isn't supported in IE, otherwise I would suggest that.